# Get hourly statistics with Google Analytics API

Tags: php, html, google-analytics

I want to build a simple page that display hourly statistics from `gapi.class.php` for the last 23 hours. So I wrote the code below, but something seems of. It displays the same statistics for multiple hours.

```
define('ga_email','$email');
define('ga_password','$password');
define('ga_profile_id',$analyticsid);

require('Including/php/gapi-1.3/gapi.class.php');

$number = 1;
$temp = 0;

while($number < 24) {
    $start = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-$number hours"));
    $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-$temp hours"));

    $ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);
    //$dimensions, $metrics, $sort_metric=null, $filter=null, $start_date=null, $end_date=null, $start_index=1, $max_results=30)
    $ga->requestReportData(
        ga_profile_id,
        array('browser'),
        array('pageviews','visits','visitors','avgTimeOnSite','percentNewVisits','visitBounceRate','UniquePageviews',),
        array('-visits'), 
        null, 
        $start,
        $date,
        1,
        30
    );

    ${'visits'.$number} = $ga->getVisits();
    ${'pageviews'.$number} = $ga->getPageviews();
    ${'bounces'.$number} = $ga->getVisitBounceRate();
    ${'visitors'.$number} = $ga->getVisitors();
    ${'date'.$number} = $date;

    $temp++;
    $number++;

}
```

and then display this in a simple table - I used a while loop, which builds this table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Hours:</th>
        <th>-1</th>
        <th>-2</th>
        <th>-3</th>
        <th>-4</th>
        <th>-5</th>
        <th>-6</th>
        <th>-7</th>
        <th>-8</th>
        <th>-9</th>
        <th>-10</th>
        <th>-11</th>
        <th>-12</th>
        <th>-13</th>
        <th>-14</th>
        <th>-15</th>
        <th>-16</th>
        <th>-17</th>
        <th>-18</th>
        <th>-19</th>
        <th>-20</th>
        <th>-21</th>
        <th>-22</th>
        <th>-23</th>                                                
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Visits:</th>
        <td><?php echo $visits1?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits2?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits3?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits4?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits5?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits6?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits7?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits8?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits9?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits10?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits11?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits12?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits13?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits14?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits15?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits16?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits17?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits18?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits19?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits20?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits21?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits22?></td>
        <td><?php echo $visits23?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Pageviews:</th>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews1?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews2?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews3?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews4?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews5?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews6?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews7?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews8?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews9?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews10?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews11?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews12?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews13?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews14?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews15?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews16?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews17?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews18?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews19?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews20?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews21?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews22?></td>
        <td><?php echo $pageviews23?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:**
So I tried Google Analytics Query Explorer 2 and I got some nice data and query url. How can I implement that in the PHP code?

Comment: It looks like you are making an API request for each hour. Are you open to making one API request for all 24 hours at once? It is possible.

Comment: To see what I mean by doing this all in one query, check out this screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/73a20826-f477-4cf4-b577-3092807f1b1f/f9cbc6fae64f341b23727d64f837cc7b/deep/0/Google-Analytics-Tools---Query-Explorer.png . It is using the very handy Google Analytics Query Explorer tool which is at http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: Yeah, I would certainly be willing to do this, since the current implementation slows the website down as well. How would I do this?

Comment: @Skram So I tried Google Analytics Query Explorer 2 and I got some nice data and query url. How can I implement that in the PHP code?

Comment: on a side note, you should read up on making use of [arrays](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) .

Comment: Because using an array is a lot more easier to code with than having 23 sets of variables. For example, instead of hardcoding 23 sets of variables in that table, you can use a loop to loop through the array and output the table elements. It would significantly cut down on your coding and make it more flexible. This doesn't speak to your immediate issue; like I said, it was a side note.